# Summation of $\sum^n_{i=0} (2i+7)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

**Summation of $\sum^n_{i=0} (2i+7)$**

How can I find that?

I tried in this way:
$$\sum^n_{i=0} \not 2 \cdot \frac{n(n+1)}{\not2}+7 $$ to find out: $$\sum^n_{i=0}(2i+7) = n(n+1)+7$$

But it seems wrong, since $$P(2): 11 = 13$$

Comment: What does $P(2):11$ denote?

Comment: @Bernard With $P(2)$ I mean replace $n$ and $i$ with 2, like the base case of the induction

Comment: It looks right to me.  $\sum_{n=0}^22n+7=0+2+4+7=13=2\cdot3+7$

Comment: $(\sum 2i)+7$ or $\sum (2i+7)$ ?

Comment: In your question do you mean $\displaystyle\Bigl(\sum_{i=0}^n 2i\Bigr)+7$ or  $\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^n( 2i+7)$?

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: Where did that $\sum^n_{i=0} \not 2 \cdot \frac{n(n+1)}{\not2}+7$ come from? Makes no sense to me at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sum^n_{i=0} (2i+7)\overset{*}{=}2\sum_{i=1}^{n}i+7\sum_{i=0}^{n}1=2\cdot\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+7(n+1)=n(n+1)+7(n+1)=(n+1)(n+7)$

- note that $\sum_{i=0}^{n}i=\sum_{i=1}^{n}i$ since summing $0$ too doesn't influence the result

Comment: Why 7 is multiplied by $(n+1)$?

Comment: @LorisSimonetti because you are summing 1 for $n+1$ times ($i$ from $0$ to $n$)

Comment: @LorisSimonetti Because it is common to interpret the $7$ as being included as a part of the summands being added by the summation... that is we are doing $(2\cdot 0 + 7) + (2\cdot 1 + 7) + (2\cdot 2 + 7) + (2\cdot 3 + 7) + \dots$  Notice that there are $n+1$ separate $7$'s in the overall sum when expanded out.

Comment: What if the summation started from $i=1$ rather than $i=0$?

Comment: What about it?  Then you'd be missing the initial term in the summation, $(2\cdot 0 + 7)$.  If you are missing that, surely you can see what influence that has on the result

Comment: @LorisSimonetti then you would have had $\sum_{i=1}^{n} (2i+7)=2\sum_{i=1}^{n}i+7\sum_{i=1}^{n}1=2\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+7\cdot n=n(n+1)+7n=n[(n+1)+7]=n(n+8)$